# TensorFlow multi class training and prediction

Tags: tensorflow

The following code (working), train a model to recognize cats and make a prediction on the selected picture. (Code TensorFlowJS but the question is generally TensorFlow)
So far it is only predicting one class ("cat"), so that a car or a dog would be for example 80% a cat. 

Question:
How do i add other classes (like "dog") ? 
Should it look like that (abstracted): model.fit([img1, img2, img3], [label1, label2, label3] ...) ?

I don't get it:
What is the relation between the labels and the training set.

Here is the code (please ignore the "Predict" part for now):

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.2.7"> </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <input id ="image-selector" class="form-control border-0" type="file"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Prediction</h2>
                <ol id="prediction-list"></ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="ml-3">Image</h2>
                <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div  id="training-images">
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image cat" src="training-images/cat.jpg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image cat" src="training-images/cat2.jpeg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image cat" src="training-images/cat3.jpeg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image cat" src="training-images/cat4.jpeg" />

        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image dog" src="training-images/dog.jpeg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image dog" src="training-images/dog2.jpeg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image dog" src="training-images/dog3.jpeg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image dog" src="training-images/dog4.jpeg" />
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    const modelType = "mobilenet";
    const model = tf.sequential();
    const label = ['cat'];
    var ys, setLabel, input, canvas, context;
    input = document.getElementById("image-selector");
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //-------------------------- Training: --------------------------------
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        // Labels
        setLabel = Array.from(new Set(label));
        ys = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(label.map((a) => setLabel.findIndex(e => e === a)), 'int32'), 10);
        console.log('ys:::'+ys);

        // Prepare model :
        model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
            inputShape: [224, 224 , 3],
            kernelSize: 5,
            filters: 8,
            strides: 2,
            activation: 'relu',
            kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
        }));
        model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 2, strides: 2}));
        model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 2, strides: 2}));
        model.add(tf.layers.flatten({}));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 64, activation: 'relu'}));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 10, activation: 'softmax'}));
        model.compile({
            loss: 'meanSquaredError',
            optimizer : 'sgd'
        });

        // Prepare training images
        var images = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            let img = preprocessImage(document.getElementsByClassName("cat")[i], modelType);
            images.push(tf.reshape(img, [1, 224, 224, 3],'resize'));
        }
        console.log("processed images : ");
        console.log(images);
        trainModel(images);
    });

    async function trainModel(images) {
        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            await model.fit(images[i], ys, {epochs: 100, batchSize: 32}).then((loss) => {
            const t = model.predict(images[i]);
            console.log('Prediction:::'+t);
            pred = t.argMax(1).dataSync(); // get the class of highest probability
            const labelsPred = Array.from(pred).map(e => setLabel[e]);
            console.log('labelsPred:::'+labelsPred);
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e.message);
            })
        }
        console.log("Training done!");
    }

    //-------------------------- Predict: --------------------------------
    input.addEventListener("change", function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(arg) {
            var src_image = new Image();
            src_image.onload = function() {
                canvas.height = src_image.height;
                canvas.width = src_image.width;
                context.drawImage(src_image, 0, 0);
                var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
                runPrediction(src_image)
            }
            src_image.src = this.result;
        });
        var res = reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    });

    async function runPrediction(imageData){
        let tensor = preprocessImage(imageData, "mobilenet");
        const resize_image = tf.reshape(tensor, [1, 224, 224, 3],'resize');
        let prediction = await model.predict(tensor).data();
        console.log('prediction:::'+ prediction);

        let top5 = Array.from(prediction)
        .map(function(p,i){
            return {
                probability: p,
                className: prediction[i]
            };
        }).sort(function(a,b){
            return b.probability-a.probability;
        }).slice(0,1);

        $("#prediction-list").empty();
        top5.forEach(function(p){
            $("#prediction-list").append(`<li>${p.className}:${p.probability.toFixed(6)}</li>`);
        });
    }

    //-------------------------- Helpers: --------------------------------
    function preprocessImage(image, modelName)
    {
        let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
        .resizeNearestNeighbor([224,224])
        .toFloat();

        let offset=tf.scalar(127.5);

        return tensor.sub(offset)
        .div(offset)
        .expandDims();
    }
</script>
```

The code is based on the TFJS documentation and a comment on the github : https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1288

**UPDATE :**
So I need X and Y to be the same length for X:images and Y:labels, with Y1 being the label for X1 and so on...

I tried:

```
ys:::Tensor (with only 2 classes represented in the training data set) :
    [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

One image + all labels -> with "model.fit(images[i], ys, {epochs: 100})...", I get:

Error: "Input Tensors should have the same number of samples as target Tensors. Found 1 input sample(s) and 10 target sample(s)."

One image + one label -> with "model.fit(images[i], ys[i], {epochs: 100})...", I get:

Error: "Cannot read property 'shape' of null", i guess ys is a tensor but y[i] is not.

All images + all labels -> with "model.fit(images, ys, {epochs: 100})...", I get:

Error: "when checking model input: the Array of Tensors that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. 
Expected to see 1 Tensor(s), but instead got the following list of Tensor(s): Tensor ..."

Guess: I need to put all images in one tensor with the same structure as ys.

**SOLVED :**

After solving the problem with the labels thanks to Rishabh Sahrawat, I had to merge all tensor(images) in to one with the help of tf.concat(...).

```
[tensorImg1, tensorImg2, tensorImg3, tensorImg4, ...] x tensor[label1, label2, label3, label4, ...]
-> 
tensor[dataImg1, dataImg2, dataImg3, dataImg4, ...] x tensor[label1, label2, label3, label4, ...]
```

Updated code :

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.2.7"> </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <input id ="image-selector" class="form-control border-0" type="file"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Prediction</h2>
                <ol id="prediction-list"></ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="ml-3">Image</h2>
                <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div  id="training-images">
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image cat" src="training-images/cat.jpg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image cat" src="training-images/cat2.jpeg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image cat" src="training-images/cat3.jpeg" />

        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image dog" src="training-images/dog.jpeg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image dog" src="training-images/dog2.jpeg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image dog" src="training-images/dog3.jpeg" />
        <img width="400" height="300" class="train-image dog" src="training-images/dog4.jpeg" />
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    const modelType = "mobilenet";
    const model = tf.sequential();
    var labels = ['cat', 'dog'];
    var ys, setLabel, input, canvas, context;
    input = document.getElementById("image-selector");
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //-------------------------- Training: --------------------------------
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {        
        // Prepare model :
        prepareModel();

        // Prepare training images
        var images = [];
        var trainLabels = []
        for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('train-image').length; i++) {
            let img = preprocessImage(document.getElementsByClassName('train-image')[i], modelType);
            //images.push(tf.reshape(img, [1, 224, 224, 3],'resize'));
            images.push(img);
            if (document.getElementsByClassName('train-image')[i].classList.contains("cat")){
                trainLabels.push(0)
            } else {
                trainLabels.push(1)
            }
        }

        console.log(labels)
        setLabel = Array.from(labels);
        ys = tf.oneHot(trainLabels, 2);
        console.log('ys:::'+ys);
        console.log(images);
        trainModel(images);
    });

    async function trainModel(images) {
        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            await model.fit(tf.concat(images, 0), ys, {epochs: 100}).then((loss) => {
            const t = model.predict(images[i]);
            console.log('Prediction:::'+t);
            pred = t.argMax().dataSync(); // get the class of highest probability
            //const labelsPred = Array.from(pred).map(e => setLabel[e]);
            //console.log('labelsPred:::'+labelsPred);
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e.message);
            })

        }
        console.log("Training done!");
    }

    //-------------------------- Predict: --------------------------------
    input.addEventListener("change", function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(arg) {
            var src_image = new Image();
            src_image.onload = function() {
                canvas.height = src_image.height;
                canvas.width = src_image.width;
                context.drawImage(src_image, 0, 0);
                var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
                runPrediction(src_image)
            }
            src_image.src = this.result;
        });
        var res = reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    });

    async function runPrediction(imageData){
        let tensor = preprocessImage(imageData, "mobilenet");
        const resize_image = tf.reshape(tensor, [1, 224, 224, 3],'resize');
        let prediction = await model.predict(tensor).data();
        console.log('prediction:::'+ prediction);

        let top5 = Array.from(prediction)
        .map(function(p,i){
            return {
                probability: p,
                className: prediction[i]
            };
        }).sort(function(a,b){
            return b.probability-a.probability;
        }).slice(0,1);

        $("#prediction-list").empty();
        top5.forEach(function(p){
            $("#prediction-list").append(`<li>${p.className}:${p.probability.toFixed(6)}</li>`);
        });
    }

    //-------------------------- Helpers: --------------------------------

    function prepareModel(){
        model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
            inputShape: [224, 224 , 3],
            kernelSize: 5,
            filters: 8,
            strides: 2,
            activation: 'relu',
            kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
        }));
        model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 2, strides: 2}));
        model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: 2, strides: 2}));
        model.add(tf.layers.flatten({}));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 64, activation: 'relu'}));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'softmax'}));
        model.compile({
            loss: 'meanSquaredError',
            optimizer : 'sgd'
        });
        model.summary()
    }

    function preprocessImage(image, modelName)
    {
        let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
        .resizeNearestNeighbor([224,224])
        .toFloat();

        let offset=tf.scalar(127.5);

        return tensor.sub(offset)
        .div(offset)
        .expandDims();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do i add other classes (like "dog") ?

You can make model predict also on another class is by adding the new class to your training dataset. Let's say you added `Dog` class, so now your dataset consists `Cat` and `Dog` pictures.

> Should it look like that (abstracted): model.fit([img1, img2, img3], [label1, label2, label3] ...)

Yes, images `x = [img1, img2, img3]` and labels to corresponding images, `y = [label1, label2, label3]`. In x, `img1` or `img2` or any other image can be a cat image or dog image. For simplicity, you can feed images represented as numpy arrays. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) is how the input training data must look like.

> What is the relation between the labels and the training set.

Labels are a part of training set. If you are performing supervised classification then labels have to be fed along with your input features (images).

**UPDATE** for updated question

```
    [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

In this you have a shape mismatch. The shape here is `(10,10)` but the model expects label input with shape `(10,)`.

If you have two classes, you don't need to represent one class with `[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]` or other with `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` in `Y` (Label). What does the rest of the zeroes do?. Just keep it simple and define as follows.

If you have a `cat` you label it `0`, and for `dog` image, you label it `1` or vice-versa. 
and then you feed it like `[0,1,0]`, here first `0` is the label for img1, `1` for img2 and `0` for img3.

Comment: Thanks, this is already helpful.
I think that it is actually what I'm doing with ys. With mapping like ['cat','dog'] => [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] and the model.fit(images, ys ...
but then get the following error in the catch section:
Input Tensors should have the same number of samples as target Tensors. Found 1 input sample(s) and 2 target sample(s). with ['cat'] => [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] no error.

Comment: `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` does this represent a batch of 10 images?

Comment: I guess this is representing the output of the prediction.
Ex: Prediction:::Tensor
     [[0.9899656, 0.0010924, 0.0010082, 0.0010883, 0.0011997, 0.0001432, 0.0001533, 0.0019973, 0.0032645, 0.0000873],]
labelsPred:::cat

Comment: I have following questions, `[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]` mentioned in your first comment, is it a batch of 10 cat images? The main cause of error is the that there is a mismatch between the lengths of number of input images and their labels. Example, on 10 images it is not receiving 10 corresponding labels or vice-versa.

Comment: No that is the result of the prediction.

Comment: To be as bit precise :
Let say i have 10 classes like ['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bear', ...], the output for a cat picture should be something like  [98.002, 1.256, 0.445, ...] wich translate to 98.002% a 'cat', 1.256 % a 'dog', ...

Comment: You are not understanding my question. Go through [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) tutorial, it has 28x28 images with10 classes like you mentioned in your last comment. If you look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification#explore_the_data), the labels `y` looks like this `array([9, 0, 0, ..., 3, 0, 5])`. If you have further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a look at the tutorial you mentioned and updated the initial post.

Comment: Read the Update please.

Comment: I just did what you suggested with 
ys = tf.tensor1d(trainLabels, 'int32');
wich returns ys:::Tensor
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

the next problem being that the model expect a tensor with an image and get an array of tensors:
Error when checking model input: the Array of Tensors that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 Tensor(s), but instead got the following list of Tensor(s): Tensor ...

I guess this is the configuration of the first layer that is posing a problem